# Build Json from database with php

Tags: php, json

I've written a simple PHP file, which pull my Data from the Database and return it with $row["fieldname"]. So now i need to know how i return is as json like below.

Normally i would start it with creating a array

```
$arr = [        
    'Name' => $row["_LSMOUSER"],
    'Pass' => $row["_LSMOPASSWORT"] ];
```

And would encode it with

```
json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

But, how i can add the Points "Rights, Masks & Key like below?

```
 {
"Users": [
    {
        "Name": "user",
        "Pass": "passwort",
        "Rights": {
            "Masks": [
                { "Key": "FAQ", "Access": true },
                { "Key": "Hilfebereich", "Access": false }  
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "user2",
        "Pass": "passwort2",
        "Rights": {
            "Masks": [
                { "Key": "FAQ", "Access": true },
                { "Key": "Hilfebereich", "Access": true }   
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: How the data about `Rights` is stored in your database?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$arr = array(        
'Name' => $row["_LSMOUSER"],
'Pass' => $row["_LSMOPASSWORT"], 
'Rights'=>array(
    'Masks'=>array( array('Key'=>'FAQ', 'Access'=>true), 
                    array('Key'=>'Hilfebereich', 'Access'=>false) 
                  )
    ) 
 );


// OutPut
"Name": "user",
"Pass": "passwort",
    "Rights": {
        "Masks": [
            { "Key": "FAQ", "Access": true },
            { "Key": "Hilfebereich", "Access": false }  
        ]
    }
```

then `json_encode($arr)`